# Mock 3rd-party service (BrainTree) - Akka HTTP

Tags: mocking, akka, braintree, akka-http

I am really new to Akka HTTP and I faced the issue below. 
I want to write some tests for routes which call a 3rd-party service. This service serves a JSON response. I think that the best solution is to implement a mock server in my app to serve the appropriate responses. 
What is the best approach to implement this functionality?

Get payments method:

```
def getPaymentMethod(paymentMethodRequest: PaymentOptionRequest): (Boolean, PaymentOption) = {
    val result = gateway.paymentMethod().find(paymentMethodRequest.paymentMethodToken)

    (true, convertPaymentMethodToPaymentOption(result))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Functional Approach**

Presumably the `getPaymentMethod` method is being invoked inside of a `Route`, something similar to:

```
val route : Route = 
  get {
    val paymentMethodRequest = ???

    val (validPayment, methodOption) = getPaymentMethod(paymentMethodRequest)

    complete(???)
  }
```

One possible way to test `route` with a "mock server" is to re-organize the route to be a higher-order function that takes in the payment method getter:

```
def createRoute(paymentMethodGetter : (PaymentOptionRequest) => (Boolean, PaymentOption)) : Route = 
  get {
    val paymentMethodRequest = ???

    val (validPayment, methodOption) = paymentMethodGetter(paymentMethodRequest)

    complete(???)
  }
```

Using the new method signature you can still create a route in your production code that goes to the third party:

```
val route = createRoute(getPaymentMethod _)
```

And you can create a route in your test code that returns data from a file:

```
val dataFromTestFile = ???

//ignores the option request and reads data from a file
val mockServer : (PaymentOptionRequest) => (Boolean, PaymentOption) = 
  _ => (True, dataFromTestFile)

val route = createRoute(mockServer)
```

This will allow you to test the rest of your route's logic with stub data.